# Selectores múltiples seleccionar elementos con old Laravele Blade

Tags: laravel, select, blade, in-array

Tengo un formulario en blade en el que hay un campo `<select>` con el `multiple` activado, para poder seleccionar más de una opción. Como es lógico, el formulario va  a un controlador donde se valida. La cuestión es que si no pasa la validación y se devuelve el control al formulario, las opciones que estuvieran seleccionadas deben seguir seleccionadas, mediante el helper `old()`.

Ahora bien, como es un múltiple, el dato ha pasado como matriz, y vuelve como matriz, con lo que `old()`, si volvemos de la validación, contiene una matriz con las opciones seleccionadas. Yo lo he puesto así:

```
<select class="form-control" id="city_ids" name="city_ids[]" size="10" multiple>
    <option value="00" class="sin-asignacion" {{ old('city_ids') ? ((@in_array('00', old('city_ids'))) ? " selected":"") : " selected" }}>CREAR SIN ASIGNAR</option>
    <option value="" disabled></option>
    @foreach ($cities as $city)
        <option value="{{ $city->id }}" {{ (@in_array($city->id, old('city_ids'))) ? " selected":"" }}>
            {{ $city->name }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Como veis, cada opción debo buscarla en la matriz, con `in_array`, para ver si está seleccionada o no. El problema es que la primera vez que se carga el formulario, antes de pasar por la validación, `old('city_ids')` es `null`, por lo que al usar `in_array` lanza una excepción. Yo lo he resuelto, como se ve en el código, usando `@`, para que no salte la excepción. Funcionar, funciona, pero me parece un poco chapuza. Estoy segura que blade, o el `old()`, tienen alguna salida más elegante, más al estilo de Laravel. Alguno habéis resuelto esto de una forma más "limpia"? Podéis darme alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

También podría evitar el error, pasando como segundo parámetro el valor por defecto cuando el helper  `old('city_ids')` retorne `null`.

Para este caso sería un `array` vacío .

```
(in_array($city->id, old('city_ids', [] )))
```

Comment: Me temo que no te sigo. De dónde sale la variable $recarga? Debe generarse en el controlador? Si es así, donde, y a partir de qué? Gracias.

Comment: @Laura1995 no, error mio, debe ser `$city` que corresponde a elemento iterado del `foreach`

Comment: Sería bueno que expliquen el voto negativo para mejorar la respuesta 3:)

Comment: Hola. Lo que has puesto funciona, No sé por qué te han puesto el negativo, quizá por ser muy escueto, pero funciona. Gracias.